# How expensive or hard would it be to add RUN button into Software Manager?

Tags: software-center

I teach Linux and quite frequently install new software, test it and remove it. I promote the use of Linux and recommend it to my relatives and friends. One common use case is I hear what people need, so I try different programs which suits best for ones needs. For example, I tested loads of kids games for my niece, found only few which suited for her age. It is infuriating to search each game or app from menu, when you could just RUN it from where you installed it, then Remove it if its not suitable and search for yet another app.

Other platforms have this (Android, IOS, Windows at least) and for a good reason. It just is so intuitive to launch an app right after you installed it.

This button will in no way hinder those who run there apps some other way, from terminal or menu.

If I was able to do this myself, how big task would it be? If I was to pay for somebody to do this, how much would it cost? I want to estimate how difficult this thing is, so I would be wiser as to pursuit it or forget it.

Comment: You may want to report this as a "bug" at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/. The report will most likely be assigned the `wishlist` tag and maybe it will be implemented.

Comment: I dont see this as a bug, for me it is just an interface lacking a feature.

Comment: Could there be a hack of some sort? Like getting the name of the installed programs executable file and run it? Something like: from command line $apt-get somethingsomething /something -> Button, then adding the Button to manager, and when pressing the Button it would type "executablename" Enter to command line. Or any hack, if this one does not make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a fairly simple task if you are acquainted well with the `software-center` codebase. It should be possible to use `dpkg`, `apt` or just manually scrape the Applications directory (`/usr/share/applications/`) to find the main `.desktop` file associated with a file and run it automatically when the button is pressed.

However, if you wanted to pay someone else to write the code for that instead and have it merged into the software-center codebase, I imagine it would cost you between $50-250, depending on who you ask and how well you can convince them that it is useful.